# Deploying django app on heroku - requested URL not found on server

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

I've been following the djangogirl's tutorial here http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/deploy/README.html on deploying a django app on Heroku. I am a complete newbie at this so a lot of the stuff just seems like black magic to me, and I have a very fuzzy idea of what is going on. However, I seem to have been able to get everything going smoothly from creating my app to pushing it onto a remote repository and running the web process.

```
>heroku create
>git push heroku master
>heroku ps:scale web=1
```

When I open the url of the app after this, I get a 'requested url not found on this server' error page, which the tutorial says is expected since I have not filled up the empty database. So it says to run

```
>heroku run python manage.py migrate
>heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser
```

When I ran them both commands seemed to execute fine. I tried running `manage.py migrate` again just to be sure but it simply said that there were no more migrations to apply. I can log in fine into the admin page, but trying to open the app url itself still gives me a 'requested url was not found on this server' error page, even after I applied migrations.

Like I said, I'm a real newbie, so I'm at a lost as to how I should troubleshoot this. I've been following the tutorial step-by-step and have no clue where I've went wrong. Help is much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Here is the output from `heroku info -s`:

```
    addons=heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
    archived_at=
    buildpack_provided_description=Python
    create_status=complete
    created_at=2015/02/10 05:02:00 -0800
    domain_name=aqiblog.herokuapp.com
    dynos=1
    git_url=https://git.heroku.com/aqiblog.git
    id=33873439
    name=aqiblog
    owner_delinquent=false
    owner_email=***
    owner_name=***
    region=us
    released_at=2015/02/10 05:33:50 -0800
    repo_migrate_status=complete
    repo_size=9458
    requested_stack=
    slug_size=53579300
    stack=cedar-14
    updated_at=2015/02/10 06:04:30 -0800
    web_url=https://aqiblog.herokuapp.com/
    workers=0
```

Here is the output from `heroku logs`. To my untrained eye nothing seems out of the ordinary:

```
2015-02-10T14:04:49.315067+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" hos
t=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=15e74a24-32e9-4a74-ab2f-696c63853b72 fwd="183
.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=267
2015-02-10T14:06:59.516339+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" hos
t=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=12b8b705-4820-46c4-9195-a04740ad138a fwd="183
.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=267
2015-02-10T14:20:16.661117+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" hos
t=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=599be313-368a-4f66-900f-a459ef42b9ff fwd="183
.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=267
2015-02-10T14:30:13.477370+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin
/" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=91f04bfd-e7b9-41a4-b905-4b7d26861cc5 fw
d="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=43ms status=302 bytes=391
2015-02-10T14:30:13.800060+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin
/login/?next=/admin/" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=301b7aee-0f48-432f-a
9a9-6696b14fe6be fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=55ms status
=200 bytes=2368
2015-02-10T14:30:14.193976+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/css/base.css" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=d04f60ed-eef6-4678-a
3f0-e133b55df175 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=
304 bytes=136
2015-02-10T14:30:14.463950+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/css/login.css" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=35ba7b7f-8ca2-40e5-
b274-5a33138a7478 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=6ms status
=304 bytes=136
2015-02-10T14:30:14.845040+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/img/nav-bg.gif" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=6b9ba7e5-b520-46d2
-ae47-776340e6eac4 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=4ms statu
s=304 bytes=136
2015-02-10T14:30:31.563636+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/admi
n/login/?next=/admin/" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=8cb9b343-f93d-4f14-
9803-592614b17b2f fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=132ms stat
us=302 bytes=625
2015-02-10T14:30:31.910829+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin
/" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=12df9c3c-4b60-4446-9094-ef567912c19f fw
d="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=68ms status=200 bytes=3837
2015-02-10T14:30:32.260761+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/css/dashboard.css" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=194ab120-f85f-4
78f-bd05-2bd5b424177d fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=4ms st
atus=304 bytes=136
2015-02-10T14:30:32.558809+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/img/icon_addlink.gif" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=b1867188-e93
5-42eb-a12e-3342d6b09fd2 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=3ms
 status=304 bytes=136
2015-02-10T14:30:32.556672+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/img/default-bg.gif" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=c9cd25cf-5bd9-
49ca-acb8-78c14d1cdffd fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=4ms s
tatus=304 bytes=136
2015-02-10T14:30:32.958179+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/img/icon_changelink.gif" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=46672886-
026d-4e44-bbda-0a46c738688f fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=
4ms status=304 bytes=136
2015-02-10T14:30:37.016120+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin
/blog/post/" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=024f5a16-2afa-46ae-901f-d9c95
d7ffac8 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=89ms status=200 byte
s=3466
2015-02-10T14:30:37.392657+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin
/jsi18n/" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=175746a8-6269-499c-9539-e94442df
3740 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=45ms status=200 bytes=2
551
2015-02-10T14:30:37.353918+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/css/changelists.css" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=4b1968b8-5977
-49d2-92c7-7f8e6f83bcce fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms
status=200 bytes=5523
2015-02-10T14:30:37.353954+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/js/core.js" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=2765ef40-cf94-4e80-af2
3-df2bd41c29fd fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=20
0 bytes=7182
2015-02-10T14:30:37.664695+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=
ab90b0a5-c743-4a36-8cf8-a45bcdb26c10 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms
 service=3ms status=200 bytes=3515
2015-02-10T14:30:37.676047+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/js/jquery.min.js" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=d793e5e6-f05c-41
7a-bc14-c726b217a873 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=11ms st
atus=200 bytes=92913
2015-02-10T14:30:37.672663+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/js/jquery.init.js" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=7494223b-6a43-4
861-93c6-8a902e8f0b1f fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=3ms st
atus=200 bytes=608
2015-02-10T14:30:37.922666+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/js/actions.min.js" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=4481557e-e808-4
5c7-9948-2856409b9f9c fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=4ms st
atus=200 bytes=3320
2015-02-10T14:30:39.773435+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/img/tooltag-add.png" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=d1e06eca-e54e
-44a4-b4c6-b834751c52b8 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=3ms
status=200 bytes=371
2015-02-10T14:30:39.795367+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/img/nav-bg-reverse.gif" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=7df78871-e
7a8-4a47-9260-7b1f715b2293 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=2
ms status=304 bytes=136
2015-02-10T14:30:43.715783+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin
/blog/" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=c8c26fb6-7c06-424a-96a3-ed7d7acf52
15 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=62ms status=200 bytes=260
6
2015-02-10T14:30:44.051139+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/css/base.css" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=a9525efc-ca5b-40a2-b
79c-0d1c7ea8f323 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=2ms status=
304 bytes=136
2015-02-10T14:30:46.623963+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin
/" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=6e2f037e-1156-4ecb-ab9a-c629746701bc fw
d="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=67ms status=200 bytes=3837
2015-02-10T14:33:37.383948+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin
/auth/user/" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=2e7aca9b-bf1a-4bca-a64e-4958c
50d2bc3 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=107ms status=200 byt
es=6954
2015-02-10T14:33:37.795450+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/css/base.css" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=427f5971-4d88-4876-b
d34-3d61219d0ee0 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=
304 bytes=136
2015-02-10T14:33:38.115038+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/css/changelists.css" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=1011a5b1-f3e3
-4ccd-bb79-decbb9f04bab fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms
status=304 bytes=136
2015-02-10T14:33:38.144837+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin
/jsi18n/" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=713139f7-188f-4dbb-8c06-f187256f
7f69 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=45ms status=200 bytes=2
551
2015-02-10T14:33:38.404063+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/js/jquery.init.js" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=5135b182-dc2e-4
a74-b8a2-5d6c0ab12db4 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms st
atus=304 bytes=136
2015-02-10T14:33:38.400444+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/js/core.js" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=de86c5af-1a29-430f-a65
1-dc6cf1fd48bf fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=30
4 bytes=136
2015-02-10T14:33:38.415586+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/js/jquery.min.js" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=19c89d3d-5d23-41
09-979e-b8bb3f42199a fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=2ms sta
tus=304 bytes=136
2015-02-10T14:33:38.408607+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/img/icon_searchbox.png" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=c5a70735-1
712-4040-9eb5-6b7dee13abd2 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1
ms status=200 bytes=620
2015-02-10T14:33:38.406036+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=
893d6f5c-af8b-4532-8aa3-6934250950c4 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms
 service=2ms status=304 bytes=136
2015-02-10T14:33:38.412860+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/js/actions.min.js" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=2dcac6b1-bb61-4
ccd-b2ec-25ecacf72228 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms st
atus=304 bytes=136
2015-02-10T14:33:38.772975+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/img/changelist-bg.gif" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=4e6c781c-37
35-43f8-9e00-6b553737b3a6 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1m
s status=200 bytes=301
2015-02-10T14:33:38.674202+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/img/icon-yes.gif" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=e9851dfa-c05f-49
09-a4c4-367907fb285c fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms sta
tus=200 bytes=551
2015-02-10T14:33:38.777309+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/img/nav-bg.gif" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=e1f74192-01f4-4036
-9a9d-79526979186a fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms statu
s=304 bytes=136
2015-02-10T14:33:38.790954+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/img/nav-bg-selected.gif" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=1fa8c87c-
67f7-473d-b783-bdff4120a7ce fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=
2ms status=200 bytes=517
2015-02-10T14:33:38.784201+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/img/sorting-icons.gif" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=c712ebb1-65
e6-45ab-96b5-7a993386ce77 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2m
s status=200 bytes=621
2015-02-10T14:33:43.504537+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin
/" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=4de8523a-32a3-4038-baca-1da937d8bcc2 fw
d="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=63ms status=200 bytes=3837
2015-02-10T14:33:43.831076+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/css/dashboard.css" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=e0bb91fd-3202-4
003-adb3-c56c968cace9 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms st
atus=304 bytes=136
2015-02-10T14:33:47.175588+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin
/logout/" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=9262fa61-6ca5-471d-b640-267022e8
51a7 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=76ms status=200 bytes=1
695
2015-02-10T14:33:54.172429+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" hos
t=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=8cf14925-254e-464e-9989-97663a447176 fwd="183
.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=267
2015-02-10T14:57:48.546469+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `pyt
hon manage.py migrate` by aquietimmanence@gmail.com
2015-02-10T14:57:54.603274+00:00 heroku[run.5781]: Awaiting client
2015-02-10T14:57:54.648369+00:00 heroku[run.5781]: Starting process with command
 `python manage.py migrate`
2015-02-10T14:57:54.901926+00:00 heroku[run.5781]: State changed from starting t
o up
2015-02-10T14:57:57.659853+00:00 heroku[run.5781]: State changed from up to comp
lete
2015-02-10T14:57:57.650205+00:00 heroku[run.5781]: Process exited with status 0
2015-02-10T15:35:07.305786+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGT
ERM
2015-02-10T15:35:08.786505+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-02-10T15:35:05.251964+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2015-02-10T15:35:05.253030+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2015-02-10T15:48:14.796557+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2015-02-10T15:48:20.976179+00:00 app[web.1]: serving on http://0.0.0.0:22300
2015-02-10T15:48:14.800364+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to start
ing
2015-02-10T15:48:19.187658+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `w
aitress-serve --port=22300 mysite.wsgi:application`
2015-02-10T15:48:21.486158+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to u
p
2015-02-10T15:48:31.912164+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/css/base.css" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=8db52772-ce7d-4c5d-a
b49-07cbe01ebaf7 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=
200 bytes=14265
2015-02-10T15:48:22.898514+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" hos
t=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=df78cf63-b28a-4986-947b-82b7229b6c22 fwd="183
.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=22ms status=404 bytes=267
2015-02-10T15:48:32.904690+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/css/login.css" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=f01a7d1e-d3da-4ce2-
a596-49c502c148a9 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=6ms status
=200 bytes=1208
2015-02-10T15:48:31.526354+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin
/login/?next=/admin/" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=28cd2f09-49fe-4327-a
b6c-4fadd62b32db fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=32ms status
=200 bytes=2368
2015-02-10T15:48:33.516041+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/img/nav-bg.gif" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=ad4a834a-814a-4a95
-926f-9356f0ee8939 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms statu
s=200 bytes=517
2015-02-10T15:48:31.127574+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin
/" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=1a5c7e5a-e4b7-4a9d-a141-df959928fe81 fw
d="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=302 bytes=390
2015-02-10T15:49:01.840359+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/admi
n/login/?next=/admin/" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=4287d109-c80e-4e43-
acc1-b047f63af3bc fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=140ms stat
us=200 bytes=2540
2015-02-10T15:49:02.187422+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/img/icon_error.gif" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=feb59db0-4c11-
495b-80f2-a5923fc73c6f fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=3ms s
tatus=200 bytes=571
2015-02-10T15:49:21.789377+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/img/nav-bg-reverse.gif" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=36deb932-f
4b7-433b-99dc-5926493a7c89 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=3
ms status=200 bytes=430
2015-02-10T15:49:22.319427+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/admi
n/login/?next=/admin/" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=5fdd060f-1513-4816-
a6eb-203c999af731 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=134ms stat
us=200 bytes=2540
2015-02-10T15:49:56.826400+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/admi
n/login/?next=/admin/" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=f3d1e006-6e9c-436b-
bf1a-c4d4f05532d4 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=10ms service=187ms sta
tus=200 bytes=2540
2015-0
2-10T15:49:57.955395+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admi
n/css/login.css" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=a918b235-0698-4ce4-80d0-a
96d8dfc0610 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304 b
ytes=136
2015-02-10T15:49:59.906654+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/css/base.css" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=15773995-4c99-459a-9
029-ee456371f894 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=
304 bytes=136
2015-02-10T15:50:01.261517+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/img/icon_error.gif" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=3b313279-e294-
42c0-8aa5-f41debcb637e fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=5ms s
tatus=304 bytes=136
2015-02-10T15:50:05.242912+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/img/nav-bg.gif" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=6a0162e3-ec3b-445c
-b8df-82d5ac6febb2 fwd="183.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms statu
s=304 bytes=136
2015-02-10T15:57:25.175840+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" hos
t=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=0d15d2cb-81e6-4482-bb62-b6182a994ad7 fwd="183
.90.125.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=267
2015-02-10T15:59:35.740276+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" hos
t=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=7b4581c2-94d7-4835-a46c-632690169036 fwd="180
.255.248.125" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=267
2015-02-10T15:59:36.759656+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favic
on.ico" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=2f3cc9e1-c086-4725-b9ab-1ec6973c41
16 fwd="180.255.248.125" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=278

2015-02-10T17:00:33.167613+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2015-02-10T17:00:33.168670+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2015-02-10T17:00:36.185466+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGT
ERM
2015-02-10T17:00:37.952348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-02-10T17:34:28.848841+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2015-02-10T17:34:28.849165+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to start
ing
2015-02-10T17:34:36.106173+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `w
aitress-serve --port=31126 mysite.wsgi:application`
2015-02-10T17:34:38.613422+00:00 app[web.1]: serving on http://0.0.0.0:31126
2015-02-10T17:34:39.197559+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to u
p
2015-02-10T17:34:40.974208+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin
" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=42a56ba0-c220-4c9c-916f-0eede44bfee9 fwd
="79.199.237.241" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=22ms status=301 bytes=257
2015-02-10T17:34:41.125316+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin
/" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=3388a9c4-f5ee-40a5-9ac8-a05d7568854e fw
d="79.199.237.241" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=20ms status=302 bytes=390
2015-02-10T17:34:41.293835+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin
/login/?next=/admin/" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=3ae35f86-8510-4cf3-a
0e5-f2a0ce41248b fwd="79.199.237.241" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=43ms status
=200 bytes=2368
2015-02-10T17:34:41.985024+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/css/base.css" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=19153867-5c26-41ca-a
8aa-d62e8094a02b fwd="79.199.237.241" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=5ms status=
200 bytes=14265
2015-02-10T17:34:42.139780+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/css/login.css" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=7b798b7b-7850-43b4-
927b-2343eacc5582 fwd="79.199.237.241" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=5ms status
=200 bytes=1208
2015-02-10T17:34:43.024133+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/img/nav-bg.gif" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=20fa5217-01eb-4615
-bd4f-b53aaee0421c fwd="79.199.237.241" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=5ms statu
s=200 bytes=517
2015-02-10T17:34:44.289787+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favic
on.ico" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=4bfc9795-d61c-402c-afd5-08bfe0564b
38 fwd="79.199.237.241" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=11ms status=404 bytes=278

2015-02-10T17:34:44.446558+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favic
on.ico" host=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=131a1b9d-cac0-4410-ae02-0ab562e6b2
2b fwd="79.199.237.241" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=278
2015-02-10T17:35:08.338710+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" hos
t=aqiblog.herokuapp.com request_id=4fd6af83-32f4-4ba2-8117-1e0914ac8882 fwd="79.
199.237.241" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=267
2015-02-10T18:41:59.962983+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2015-02-10T18:41:59.963483+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2015-02-10T18:42:04.360383+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGT
ERM
2015-02-10T18:42:06.591219+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

Also, I'm working on Windows 8, and I'm still new to working with the commandline, so if this requires any command line troubleshooting I'd appreciate greatly if you could give me Windows commands (though I'd gladly search up Windows equivalents if you give me Unix commands)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Good first question - you've related what you tried, what the error was, and attempts to resolve the issue. Hopefully somebody familiar with Heroku can give you a hint in the right direction.

Comment: What URL are you going to when you see the message? And can you give more details of the error: is it a Django error page, and can you paste the full error?

Comment: hi, the url is aqiblog.herokuapp.com. This gives a 'requested url not found page', but aqiblog.herokuapp.com/admin/ loads fine and I can log in fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I seem to have managed to fix it, though I don't know what the exact issue was. The first change I made was to add the line

```
psybopg2==2.5.4
```

in the requirements.txt file, which the tutorial said was required but which I seemed to miss out (alas). But even after deploying the updated repository I still got the same 'URL not found'  error page. My next change(made out of desperation) which I think wouldn't have affected anything, was to add spaces between the '=' sign in some assignment statements in the mysite\settings.py file. After deployment, still no luck.

I decided at this point to move ahead with the tutorial and figure out this problem later, so I tweaked with and created a few files that shouldn't have affected the deployment process (edited mysite\urls.py, blog\views.py, created blog\urls.py and a html template file, post_list.html). Then I realized that I had followed the tutorial to put

```
python-3.4.2
```

in the runtime.txt file, but I was running python-3.4.1 locally, so I changed the specified version number. This time, after deployment, I got a Server Error(500), but I was suspicious of the backslash that I had put in the path specifying the template which a view defined in mysite\view.py would render (namely, blog\post_list.html), so that the website would run without error locally (on Windows). Replacing with the forward slash (blog/post_list.html) and deploying again, it miraculously works!

So what I'm suspecting is that changing the python runtime was what solved the problem, but then again, why would it? Doesn't Heroku default to using Python 2.7.9 if you leave it unspecified, and how does the local version of python affect the running of the files on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the URL you are visiting is equivalent to the one outputted when running the following command:

```
heroku info -s | grep web_url | cut -d= -f2
```

Also, if you run the following, do you see anything out of the ordinary?

```
heroku logs
```

Comment: Hmm I forgot to add that I'm working on Windows system, so I'm not sure that the first command works (certainly grep and cut wouldn't work). But I've tried running `heroku info -s -a eon-testing` and I get `! You do not have access to the app eon-testing`. I've been trying to understand what the `-a eon-testing` part does but the help file doesn't specify any arguments beyond -s. In any case, I've posted the `heroku logs` and `heroku info -s` outputs in an edit. web_url corresponds to the URL I'm trying to visit.

Comment: Oops, that's my fault, sorry. I had included the `-a eon-testing` to test it locally on an app I was working on to make sure I was telling you the right thing, and forgot to tell you to remove it. The `-a` option allows you to specify an application, but is unnecessary for you since you only have the one.  Can you edit your question with the output of `heroku run python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Also perhaps `heroku run "python manage.py migrate --list"`.  Note the quotes around the command to run on heroku - that tells it to output the list of migrations it has/can run.

Comment: ah, fixed it, somehow, almost magically it seems, but thanks for your help :) though do you think I've identified the issue correctly?

Comment: Yeah it's possible - Heroku should default to using python 2.7 as I recall, so if you need python 3.x then that could be it.  Glad you got it sorted!